# Uniqueness of linear combinations upon a vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

## TASK:

Show that in an n-dimensional vector space X, the representation of
any x as a linear combination of given basis vectors $e_{1},..,e_{n}$ is
unique.

## Attempt:

Let X be a vector space with dimenstion $\dim{X}=n$.Let $e=\{e_{1},..,e_{n}\}$ be a cannonical basis.

#### We want to proof that $x \in X$ is a unique linear combination:

$$x=\alpha_{1}e_{1}+...+\alpha_{n} e_{n}$$

#### Assumption

Lets assume that for scalars $\beta_{1},..,\beta_{n},\alpha_{i} \neq \beta_{i}, i =\overline{1,n}$ we can represent

By definition, every vector space is a field, which means that for every vector $x \in X$ and every scalar $\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{n}$
$$\alpha_i(x_1+x_2)=\alpha_i x_1 + \alpha_i x_2$$
$$(\alpha_i + \beta_i) x = \alpha_i x + \beta_i x$$

#### Question1:

if the two representations are the same, does that mean that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{i} x_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_{i} x_{i}$$

and if so, would that mean that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\alpha_{i} -\beta_{i}) x_{i} =0$$

But that would mean that they are linearly dependant?

#### Question 2:

maybe I have to make a construction that involves a vector of scalars $\gamma=(\gamma_1,..,\gamma_{n}),\gamma_{i}=\alpha_{i}-\beta_{i},\forall i=\overline{1,n}$

#### Question 3:

How can this statement be proven?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\alpha_{i} -\beta_{i}) e_{i} =0\implies \alpha_{i} =\beta_{i}$.

Comment: @ThomasShelby Why should this implication be valid ?

Comment: Because  $\{e_i\}_i$ is a basis and hence a linearly independent set.

Answer (score 2):

Your 'Question 1' is the key:
if a vector can be written as two different linear combinations of some vectors $e_i$, then - as you observed - it yields to a nontrivial zero combination of them, hence $e_i$ are linearly dependent.

Putting it in contrapositive: if $e_i$ is linearly independent, any vector can be written as at most one linear combination of them.